# Start typing anywhere on a sheet

Tags: microsoft-word, documents

Would anyone know if it is possible to 'preformat' a Word doc so that I can click and start to type **anywhere** on the sheet (within the margin limits), rather than at the (default) top left.

If feature is not available in Word, is there any freeware to do this ?

Comment: Word - as all other word processors - is designed to manage text filling up a page starting from top left (or right depending on language). You may insert text boxes in any location so it'll behave as you need. Or you can try publishing tools or presentation editors, those may better fit your needs.

Comment: Is **double**clicking anywhere on the sheet and start typing working for you?

Comment: Brilliant !!!!!!! Works well.

Answer (score 0):

When you start typing in an arbitrary location, it leaves the question of where the text should wrap. To solve the wrapping issue, you should contain the text in a *text box*.

Instructions for Word 365 (2016) follow. Other versions of Word may have slightly different menus but the functionality should exist back to 2003, perhaps earlier.

1. Go to the Insert tab on the ribbon.
2. Select Text Box => Simple Text Box
3. While on the Format tab (default), select Shape Outline => No Outline
4. Position and size the text box as desired, and type in it.

If you want to simplify this process for frequent use, you can:

- Select the text box and go Insert => Text Box => Save Selection to Text Box Gallery so you can skip the outline adjustment next time.

or

- Save the document with a single no-outline text box as a template, so you can open a new document with a borderless text box from the start.

[image: GIF showing process]

Comment: Regretably I'm still using word 2007 so this nice idea doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Even Word 2007 supports text boxes. Pretty much any version that’s still good for use does.

Comment: @altikaka It's more or less the same in 2007: https://www.gcflearnfree.org/word2007/working-with-text-boxes/1/

Comment: Thanks everyone for your contributions. I am using the simplest suggestion of a double left click which does the job.